# Why are certain indexed entries being excluded from results? Could it be the special Status?

Tags: search, low-search

It seems I can't access certain indexed entries in a collection. 
Here are my form and results tags:

```
{exp:low_search:form channel="exposiciones|eventos|talleres|publicaciones" query="{segment_3}" result_page="search/results" no_result_page="search/noresults" search_in="everywhere" show_expired="yes" show_future_entries="yes" status="not closed" where="all" form_class="search_form" form_id="my_search_form" secure="no" loose_ends="yes"}

{exp:low_search:results
      query="{segment_3}"
      status="not draft" 
      collection="exposiciones"
    }
```

I use Low Search to divide my results sets into different collections. But even if I use  collection="all" and keyword ="" I get all results but the ones I cant access.

NOTE: The missing entries have a a custom Status, which is NOT part of the default "Statuses" group! Could this be the reason I cannot access them?

Comment: Why are your status parameters different? status="not closed" and status="not draft"

Comment: Are entries showing when you set the status to "open"?

Comment: Ive tried many combinations of statuses, includen open, all, not closed, not draft, and ommiting the whole thing.. The conflicting status is called "Slider", which as I've stated is not part of the EE default Statuses group. Im using Publisher add on, with Low Search add onn for that BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Low Search doesn't work like EE's Simple Search. Most of the attributes you have set on the Form tag will do nothing, especially since Low Search v3. The `no_result_page`, `search_in` and `where` attributes do not belong to Low Search. Only [these parameters](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#form-tag-parameters) are valid for the Form tag. Move the others to the Results tag instead. So you'll get:

```
{exp:low_search:form
    query="{segment_3}"
    result_page="search/results"
    form_class="search_form"
    form_id="my_search_form"
}
    ...
{/exp:low_search:form}

{exp:low_search:results
    query="{segment_3}"
    collection="exposiciones"
    channel="exposiciones|eventos|talleres|publicaciones"
    show_expired="yes"
    show_future_entries="yes"
    status="not closed"
    loose_ends="yes"
}
    ...
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

A couple of things could cause an entry to not show up:

- You have specified both `collection` and `channel`. Only entries from the channel associated with the given `collection` will be returned.
- The keywords given should contain terms that are present in the collection index. If the term is in a field that has 0 weight, the entry will not be returned, as the field is not part of the index.

Remember, the Results tag works just like the native channel:entries tag, just with added goods.

Comment: Thanks Low! That worked! It was the show_expired="yes" on the results tag that made it happen! I had it on the form tag. On question though. I am a bit confused, Is it necesarry to specify channel on the results tag? I thought channel = collection.

Comment: A collection is a subset of a channel, since a channel can have multiple collections. If you're defining collections in the Results tag, the results will be automatically limited to the associated channels. So you don't need to define the channel parameter in the Results tag as well.